# i want to semantic my code

Tags: javascript, html, css, semantics

hello guys good morning 
i want to semantic one of my recent project but i'm not sure about one of my code i've just created

also i have picture of that section

i want to use  tag for highlighted part in picture (please see the picture)

[image]

is it valid to use **section tag** here?

my code for this part :

```
<section class="customer-receipts">
    <div class="image-part">
        <figure>
            <img src="h56.jpg">
        </figure>
    </div>
    <div class="text-part">
        <h2>send customers digital receipts</h2>
        <section class="paper-sec">
            <h3>no paper receipts</h3>
            <p>Eliminate the need to store signed paper receipts</p>
        </section>
        <section class="paper-sec">
            <h3>searchable transactions</h3>
            <p>Every transaction you run in saved in the system for the lifetime of your business</p>
        </section>
        <section class="paper-sec">
            <h3>bra free</h3>
            <p>Every transaction you run in saved in the system for the lifetime of your business</p>
        </section>
        <section class="paper-sec">
            <h3>green technology</h3>
            <p>Every transaction you run in saved in the system for the lifetime of your business</p>
        </section>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not use the [`<section>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/section) element as a generic container; this is what [`<div>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div) is for, especially when the sectioning is only for styling purposes. A rule of thumb is that a **section should logically appear in the outline of a document**.

Use [`<article>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/article) for main wrapper.

[**Source**](https://developer.mozilla.org)

You better use the construction like this -

```html
<article class="customer-receipts">
  <section class="image-part">
    <figure>
      <img src="h56.jpg">
    </figure>
  </section>
  <section class="text-part">
    <h2>send customers digital receipts</h2>
    <div class="paper-sec">
      <h3>no paper receipts</h3>
      <p>Eliminate the need to store signed paper receipts</p>
    </div>
    <div class="paper-sec">
      <h3>searchable transactions</h3>
      <p>Every transaction you run in saved in the system for the lifetime of your business</p>
    </div>
    <div class="paper-sec">
      <h3>bra free</h3>
      <p>Every transaction you run in saved in the system for the lifetime of your business</p>
    </div>
    <div class="paper-sec">
      <h3>green technology</h3>
      <p>Every transaction you run in saved in the system for the lifetime of your business</p>
    </div>
  </section>
</article>
```

Comment: thanks but why use section in class of text part? this is just a wrapper and generic container 

and why not using section when i have heading here i use document outline and it shows as sub section 

could you clear me where to use section exactly? thanks for your answer

Comment: You better read the things about `<article>` tag. I have the link on the tag just click it in the answer. An `<article>` tag is combined with `<head>` and many `<section>`'s. An `<article>` is a part of a page and it's like a whole new document in a **HTML page** so we can outline and it shows its sub contents as `<section>`. I think you got the point and if it's a helpful answer `vote up` and if it's the answer you are looking for then please also mark it as the `answer`*(only telling this because you are a starter at SO)*.

Answer (score 0):

Read this [Section tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/section)

Section can be used if you want to display the details of a particular part of a web page. You can describe title, images or other details you want so that it would be easy to maintain your code.

For example, a home page of a website can be divided into 3 sections e.g., Intro, Apps, Upcoming apps.

Comment: what about sub section?

w3c says you are valid to use section into another section tag